# Couldn't scrape string inside a blocked div

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://fado.vn/today-deals')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find_all(class_="product-panel__price-field")
for i in price:
    print(i.text)
```

This code returns "Click để xem báo giá" which means "click to see the price" though there are actual prices in HTML. I guess they're blocking the price. Any ideas about what's the actual cause and how to pass the blocking? Please help! :<

Comment: not blocked, it dynamic page, use selenium

Comment: Nice suggestion! It worked perfectly. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thank to @ewwink, the problem solved. He suggested me using Selenimum and it worked perfectly. It’s a nice tool to navigate to page before using Beautiful soup to parse the HTML.